# Deserializing XML to Object

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xstream

I have a xml file, which is not serialized using XStream.
It may be in any custom but fixed format,
How to use XStream or any efficient api to de serialize it to Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to implement your own Converter, see this [tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html)

**Edit:** There are surely other ways (read: other packages) to sort this out, but in your question you have mentioned that you wanted to use XStream, hence my reply, and the link to tutorials there.

Comment: The question states "XStream or any efficient API".

Comment: @Blaise: my bad.. should really take my time when reading these posts... seems like my eyes are slowly giving up on me

Answer (score 1):

JAXB fits your needs. See here:

https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/

or here:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbay.html

Comment: +1 for JAXB.  Note there are multiple implementations of JAXB: Metro (the RI), EclipseLink MOXy, JaxMe, etc.  Each has useful extensions, see my answer for some of MOXy's:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069176/desearilizing-xml-to-object/4069321#4069321

Answer (score 0):

You could use the @XmlPath extension in [MOXy JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to map your object model to any XML document without worrying about writing converters.  You can also use the externalized metadata format to apply multiple mappings to your object model:

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML

Comment: The you could use the externalized metadata format and represent your metadata as XML:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML

Answer (score 0):

The most performant XML serializer is [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net). Its both faster and more memory efficient than JAXB. Its also much easier to use. Everything can be done via annotations, you do not have to deal with XML directly.